# Improve performance when using hibernate and GWT

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, gwt, gwt-designer

I have a performance issue when using hibernate and GWT. this happens if I tried to insert or load  an object from database where  I have to bind every element of the UI to the hibernate object which takes a long time, for example:

```
School sc=new School();
sc.setNo(Long.parseLong(textBox.getText));
sc.setName(textBox1.getText());
```

and so on. Is there any way to speed up this process? could I use any graphical editor like GWT designer to do that? is there any way I could bypass this problem? or Is there any tool I could use to increase performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the new GWT 2.1 editors (http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html).

One of their goals is to "Decrease the amount of glue code necessary to move data from an object graph into a UI and back." You can use them with any bean-like object.

Answer (score 0):

In extGWT

```
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.binding.FormBinding
```

helps you bind your model properties to widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks fine. It is simple and understandable. The only technologies used in the code are GWT and Java.

Introducing a new library to reduce the glue code could very likely actually reduce your productivity. So, basically I recommend the KISS (keep it simple, stupid!) approach!